# Sudden Increase in row exclusive locks and connection exhaustion in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a scenario that repeats itself every few hours. In every few hours, there is a sudden increase in **row exclusive locks** in PostgreSQL DB. In Meantime there seems that some queries are not responded in time and causes connection exhaustion to happen that PostgreSQL does not accept new clients anymore. After 2-3 minutes locks and connection numbers drops and the system comes back to normal state again.

I wonder if auto vacuum can be the root cause of this? I see analyze and vacuum (NOT FULL VACCUM) take about 20 seconds to complete on one of the tables. I have INSERT,SELECT,UPDATE and DELETE operations going on from my application and I don't have DDL commands (ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE INDEX, ...) going on. Can auto vacuum procedure conflict with queries from my application and cause them to wait until vacuum has completed? Or it's all the applications and my bad design fault? I should say one of my tables has a field of type **jsonb** that keeps relatively large data for each row (10 MB roughly).

I have attached an image from monitoring application that shows the sudden increase in row exclusive locks.

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what your chart is showing.  The green line was hovering about 200 for while, then collapsed.  But 200 what?  And 200 doesn't seem to agree with any of the average, current, or total in the legend.  What doe those mean?  I think you need to name your monitoring application, since that chart is far from self-explanatory and I don't recognize it as any of the common ones.

Comment: @jjanes the legend shows that it indicates Access Share Locks count. I think Access Share Lock is caused by pg_dump that is creating a backup from the database. Access Share Locks jump to near 200 when pg_dump starts and collapses after pg_dump is done. I have monitored and I can say that does not causes problems at least most of the times. Most of the times the blue ones, row exclusive locks are correlated with connection exhaustion problem.

Comment: Ok, I thought the collapse of the green line was the problem, or was indicative of the problem.  I think you have the causation reversed, the large number of connections are what is driving the large number of locks.  I would say the problem is something else, probably in the app.  Can you monitor for locks waited on, rather than locks held?  It doesn't matter much what locks are held, unless they are blocking things.

Answer (score 1):

`ROW EXCLUSIVE` locks are perfectly harmless; they are taken on tables against which DML statements run. Your graph reveals nothing. You should set `log_lock_waits = on` and `log_min_duration_statement` to a reasonable value. Perhaps you can spot something in the logs. Also, watch out for long running transactions.